# Radio button validations

Tags: javascript, radio-button, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I have a series of various fields on a Dynamics CRM 2011 form.  I'm using javascript to carry out various checks.  One of these is setting particular fields to "required" to prevent the user saving the form until the field is assigned a value. (Making them mandatory)

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_FieldA1").setRequiredLevel("required");
```

However, some of my fields are radio buttons.  The above code doesn't seem to work correctly for these. I think a Yes/No selection of "No" is seen as null anyway.  Which means if "No" is selected, I still get a message "You must provide a value for FieldA1".

Can anyone suggest a work around so "No" is allowed?
Thanks.

To check mandatory fields, (if particular fields are completed on the form) the user selects a radio button as the last option at the bottom of the form ("Mark this form as complete?") When Yes is selected, the following function carries out some basic checks:

```js
function FormSaveAlert()
{
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_formcompleted").getValue() == true)
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure this form is complete? \n Once saved, this form cannot be  modified again.") == false)
        {
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_formcompleted").setValue(false);
        }
        else
        {
            var HF1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_hf1field");
            HF1.setRequiredLevel("required"); 
            if (HF1.getValue()==null) {HF1.setValue(false);}
            //Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("otherfield").setRequiredLevel("required"); 
        }
    }
}
```

If the form is marked as complete, and a certain field is required but contains null, a message appears preventing a save. Default message in Dynamics - "You must provide a value for HF1"

Comment: this function is called inside onsave event or inside an onchange event? and you are still missing a closing brace

Comment: brace fixed - it's called during FormLoad

Comment: the code is ok. it's executed only when `new_formcompleted` is `Yes`, after a confirmation box will popup, if the user click `Cancel` `new_formcompleted` is set to `No`, if the user click `Ok` the field `new_hf1field` will be required and its value set to `No` only when the value is empty or when happens the bug described in my reply.

Comment: When I mark the form as complete, I get this error: http://i.imgur.com/umYNRIL.png

Answer (score 1):

I did a test and I can replicate the issue, if I set a two options to `null` and after I select `No`, `getValue` function returns `null` instead of `false`.

(I used only Google Chrome, but because is a supported customization it must works for all browsers)

If inside your requirements is possible (shows `No` as default value), I suggest to enforce the default value by code as this example:

```js
var fieldA1 = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_FieldA1");
fieldA1.setRequiredLevel("required");
if (fieldA1.getValue()==null) { fieldA1.setValue(false); }
```

Comment: Hi Guido, thanks for your example.  I've added where I am checking the fields in the original question. Can you see if this function is suitable? I'm testing it now myself, but no luck yet.

Comment: @GrumP can you please edit your post and fix the code? looks like you are missing a closing brace, and if you describe what you want to accomplish is better, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A required field must have a value, but a bit field always has a value, so I would actually expect this to be seen as containing a value even when it appears not to.

Can you post the onChange code for x_formcompleted too, since that is what is triggering the error?

You have two fields here, and I can't quite see the logic of how they interact.

Surely you need only one, which if ticked asks them to confirm and if they change their mind it gets reset.

Also consider using an option set with values yes / no / null (there is a built-in global option set for this). Make Null ("unassigned") the default, and make the field required (not by script, just always in the field properties).

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. :)  The fucntion FormSaveAlert appears to be triggering the error.  When I select the radio button for x_formcompleted.